# Python3 - Mysql - cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, debian

This program works fine on Ubuntu 10 but not in my Debian 8.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
       user='eric', 
       password='***',
       host='localhost',
       database='eric'
)

curs = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./exo.py", line 19, in <module>
    curs = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'
```

## Environment

```
pip3 list|grep mysql -> None

dpkg -l|grep mysql|grep python
ii  python3-mysql.connector          1.2.3-2                              all          pure Python implementation of MySQL Client/Server protocol (Python3)
```

Could you help me ? Thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL Connector do you have on the machine where it works?

Comment: 8.0.17 on Ubuntu 10 // 1.2.3 on Debian 8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to snakecharmed ...

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-2-0-0.html

> The mysql.connector.cursor module supports four new cursor classes:
>
> ```
> The MySQLCursorDict cursor class returns each row as a dictionary. The keys for each dictionary object are the column names of the MySQL
> ```
>
> result.
>
> cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)

So dictionnary=True doesn't exit on version 1.2.3 of mysql.connector